# Convert String Column directly to Date format (not Datetime) in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following Pandas DataFrame:

> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['2020-01-02', '2020-01-02']})

Obviously, the column 'a' is string. I want to convert it to 'Date' type; and here is what I did:

> df['a'] = df['a'].apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.date

It works, but in reality my DataFrame has 500,000 + rows. It seems to be very inefficient. Is there any way to directly and more efficiently convert string column to Date column?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.apply` is essentially a native python `for` loop.

`pandas.to_datetime` is a vectorized function, meaning it's meant to operate on sequences/lists/arrays/series by doing the inner loop in C

If we start with a larger dataframe:

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': ['2020-01-02', '2020-01-02'] * 5000})
```

And then do (in a jupyter notebook)

```
%%timeit
df['a'].apply(pandas.to_datetime).dt.date
```

We get a pretty slow result:

```
1.03 s ± 48.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But if we rearrange just slightly to pass the entire column:

```py
%%timeit
pandas.to_datetime(df['a']).dt.date
```

We get a much faster result:

```
6.07 ms ± 232 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! 
Also I combined the other answer and here it becomes even faster:
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['a'], infer_datetime_format=True).dt.date

Answer (score 1):

Below is code for the fastest function I know of for converting strings to dates, specialised for application on a series where the same dates are repeated - e.g. sub-day granularity financial time series data. If you are working with 1 minute bars and have individual date and time columns, that's a lot of repeated date strings.

```
def str_to_date(s):
    """
    This is an extremely fast approach to datetime parsing.
    For large data, the same dates are often repeated. Rather than
    re-parse these, we store all unique dates, parse them, and
    use a lookup to convert all dates.
    """

    # Create a dictionary with unique dates as keys and their corresponding
    # parsed datetime objects as values
    dates = {date: pd.to_datetime(date,
                              format="%Y-%m-%d") for date in s.unique()}

    # Map the original dates to their parsed values using the lookup dictionary
    return s.map(dates).dt.date
```

Then if we re-run all the timings with the same large DataFrame used in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66862336/3253628. First create the Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['2020-01-02', '2020-01-02'] * 5000})
```

I will pass the date format to each of the old approaches to make it fair to compare.

Time the first approach:

```
%%timeit
df['a'].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='"%Y-%m-%d").dt.date
```

For which we get:

```
621ms ± 4.12ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Time the second approach:

```
%%timeit
pd.to_datetime(df['a'], format='"%Y-%m-%d").dt.date
```

For which we get:

```
4.02 ms ± 37.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And now the new approach using the function defined above:

```
%%timeit
str_to_date(df['a'])
```

For which we get:

```
2.66 ms ± 28.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

So that is a pretty good speed up.

The same logic can also be applied when there a lot of repeated time strings and you wish to convert them to time deltas.

```
def str_to_time(s):
     """
    This is an extremely fast approach to datetime parsing.
    For large data, the same times are often repeated. Rather than
    re-parse these, we store all unique times, parse them, and
    use a lookup to convert all dates.
    """
    # Create a dictionary with unique times as keys and their corresponding
    # parsed timedelta objects as values
    times = {time: pd.to_timedelta(time) for time in s.unique()}

    # Map the original times to their parsed values using the lookup dictionary
    return s.map(times)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a'], format='%Y-%m-%d')`

specify the `format` if you know they are all following the same format.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is not about input format, which is what the `format` argument governs, but about the output format: is it a date, or a datetime? -1.